# How to put lambda in a different section with GCC?

Tags: gcc, lambda

I'm using C++11 compiler to generate embedded code and I'd like to use lambda functions in it. However I need to put the actual generated code for my lambda functions in a different section or always inline it into the function/method where it is used (by default if some lambda function is not inlined it is put into '.text' section). Is there a way to set section attribute for the lambda function? Alternatively is there a way to make GCC compiler always inline lambda functions?

Comment: Why do you need to change the section?

Comment: @user4815162342 It doesn't matter. If I say that I need to change section, then I need to change section.

Comment: It matters if there is a better way to accomplish the actual requirement - see [xy problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378). Note that I'm not claiming that you are presenting an xy problem here, only that the underlying requirement is not irrelevant on SO.

Comment: @user4815162342 I'm asking a concrete question, if you don't know the answer to the concrete question, please don't write anything.

Comment: I wasn't answering the question, I was requesting clarification in a comment, as is customary on SO. If you are unable or unwilling to provide the said clarification, feel free not to respond.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will put the lambda in the .mylambdas section

```
auto myLambda = [&]() __attribute__((section(".mylambdas")) 
{ 
  ... 
};
```

Note : There's a bug with gcc where it complains if you use the same section name for lambdas in both regular class methods and const class methods. Clang is ok.  One workaround is to use another section name for const methods, if that's possible.